# Trying to print high score on processing game and save it onto an external file to be read again

Tags: java

Im working on a project in java right now that is basically the game snake. I am finish it up by having the high score print on to an external txt file so that they can be read and written over when a high score is broken. It seems to not want to work with my parsing of the line read from the file. I need to to be an int so i can compare it to the most recent score.

```
BufferedReader reader;
PrintWriter output;
String line = "1";

reader = createReader("SnakeFile.txt");
output = createWriter("SnakeFile.txt");

try {
    line = reader.readLine();
    boolean t = true;
    while (t) {
        String score = line;
        int x = Integer.parseInt(score);
        if (x < snake.bodyLength) {
            System.out.println("New High Score" + snake.bodyLength);
            output.println(snake.bodyLength);
        }
        // line = reader.readLine();
        t = false;
    }
    // highScore = reader.readLine();
    // highScore ="5";
    // output.flush(); // Writes the remaining data to the file
    output.close(); // Finishes the file

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    line = null;
}
```

Comment: Where are your createReader("SnakeFile.txt");  and  createWriter("SnakeFile.txt"); functions defined?

Comment: they are pre defined by processesing

Comment: You are reading before writing to the file. So initially there is nothing in the file. Then you write and never read the data again in the loop where you are writing. Also close() should be in finally block.

Comment: i was using processing to make this game??